# Google Apps Script error: Cannot read property 'appendRow' of null

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Apps Script keeps giving me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendRow' of null
> AddRecord   @ Code.gs:4

The code:

```
function AddRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");
  mainSheet.appendRow(["purple", new Date()]);
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Then mainSheet is probably undefined.  Is there a space in the `MAIN` sheet name

Answer (score 0):

The following function will avoid unwanted active spreadsheet, and potential error :

```
//replace: 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//by: 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx'); 
// you will find the ID in the URL of the sheet, between "spreadsheets/d/" and "/edit"
```

If still have some issue, the problem must come from the sheet name as @Cooper already told you ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the document:

> getSheetByName(name) returns null if there is no sheet with the given name and [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) if the sheet name is found in the Spreadsheet.

There are 2 possible reasons for having a null value:

1. The sheet named `MAIN` does not exists.
2. There is a typographical error in the sheet name.

You can fix that by adding a sheet named `MAIN` or renaming your sheet to `MAIN` to remove any extra characters.

### References:

- [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Answer (score 0):

The sheet is probably not called MAIN in the file you are using.

I had a similar problem. If you have not edited the sheet prior try this:

var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

to replace this:

var mainSheet = ss.getSheetByName("MAIN");

This will reference the specific sheet in the file, and it should execute just fine then.

Answer (score 0):

i had the Problem too!
There is how I fixed that:

```
function AddRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var mainSheet = ss.getSheetName();
  var mainSheet1 = ss.getSheetByName(mainSheet);
  mainSheet1.appendRow(["purple", new Date()]);
}
```